# How can I pass an array as arguments to a function?

Tags: javascript

```
if(a == 1){
  parameter = ['1','true','a'];
}else{
  parameter = ['2','false','b'];
}

function run(a,b,c){

}
```

How can I pass an array as arguments to the function `run`? I tried JSON.Stingify but it doesn't work as I'm still seeing the array bracket in my console.log()

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript `apply()`:

```
run.apply(this, parameter);
```

Comment: wait, I mean pass the param as string. function run(a,b,c) only accept 3 string, not array.

Comment: It will pass three strings as function arguments  http://jsfiddle.net/zm0c3jhx/  Now if it isn't what you mean, edit your question with clearer expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options.

Call the function directly.

```
if(a == 1){
    run('1', 'true', 'a');
}else{
    run('2', 'false', 'b');
}
```

Or use [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call the function with an array as arguments.

```
if(a == 1){
    parameter = ['1','true','a'];
}else{
    parameter = ['2','false','b'];
}

run.apply(null, parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGaWNr

#### Code

```
x = ['2','false','b'];

var run = function (x0,x1,x2) {
    document.write (x0+'<br>');
    document.write (x1+'<br>');
    document.write (x2+'<br>');
}

run(x[0],x[1],x[2]);
```

#### Output

```
2
false
b
```